# Obfuscate React classNames in existing codebase

Tags: reactjs, sass, jsx

**Hi guys**

I am working on a big React application with an existing code-base (100+ components). Currently, we are using the traditional styling method, example:

```
JSX:
<div className="div" />

SCSS: 
.div {
 /* ... */
}
```

We are using webpack with these loaders:

```
/* ... */
use: [
       {
         loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
         options: {
           publicPath: '../'
         }
       },
       'css-loader',
       'postcss-loader',
       {
         loader: 'sass-loader',
         options: { implementation: sass }
       }
     ]
/* ... */
```

Is there any way to obfuscate these classNames from both JSX and SCSS without rewriting the whole thing? Is it also possible to rewrite only some components to be obfuscated or do we have to rewrite it all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`css-loader` has a `modules` option which when set to `true` obfuscates class names. Unfortunately, this will obfuscate all of the class names and will require you to change all usages of `<div className="div" />` to:

```
import styles from <stylesheet>;
<div className={styles.div} />
```

**Edit**:
The only way I can think of avoiding having to change all of the usages at once is by splitting your css config in webpack with two patterns, for example:

```
{
    test: /.*dirA\/.*\.css/,
    use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true } }, ...]
},
{
    test: /.*dirB\/.*\.css/,
    use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }, ...]
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I have tried the modules option already and it causes the whole css to break (normal behavior). Do you know of any other loader I could use for this specific use-case?

Comment: @CHRAIBIMohammedYassine I added an edit to my answer about splitting the files which you want to apply modules to, does this help?

Comment: @CHRAIBIMohammedYassine other than that, sorry I don't know any other loaders that could solve this use case

Comment: I tried separating the files with the syntax you provided also with
 include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "app/path/to/scss")
    ]
syntax but the problem persists. I am not able to achieve the desired goal.

Comment: What exactly happens when you tried those two things? As in what were the specific errors

Comment: No errors, but the classes were not hashed in the specific directory

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for ejected Create-react-app**

Example classNames: *a_a, a_b, a_c* .... etc.

1. Eject app
2. Install `incstr`
3. Create `getScopedName.js` at the `config` folder.

```js
const incstr = require('incstr');
const createUniqueIdGenerator = () => {
  const uniqIds = {};
  const generateNextId = incstr.idGenerator({
    alphabet: 'abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  });
  return (name) => {
    if (!uniqIds[name]) {
      uniqIds[name] = generateNextId();
    }
    return uniqIds[name];
  };
};
const localNameIdGenerator = createUniqueIdGenerator();
const componentNameIdGenerator = createUniqueIdGenerator();
module.exports = (localName, resourcePath) => {
  const componentName = resourcePath
    .split('/')
    .slice(-2, -1)[0];
  const localId = localNameIdGenerator(localName);
  const componentId = componentNameIdGenerator(componentName);
  return `${componentId}_${localId}`;
};
```

Now...

4. Open the `webpack.config.js` and add:

```js
const getScopedName = require('./getScopedName')
```

5. Find the ~445-460 rows and replace with:

```js
{
  test: cssModuleRegex,
  use: getStyleLoaders({
    importLoaders: 1,
    sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
    modules: {
      ...(isEnvDevelopment ? {
        localIdentName: '[path]_[name]_[local]',
      } : {
       getLocalIdent: (context, localIdentName, localName) => (
         getScopedName(localName, context.resourcePath)
       ),
      })
     },
  }),
}
```

It's all. :)